# Get position of another element

Tags: angular, ionic2

What's the best way to position an element on another one on Angular2 ?
My two elements have the same parent:

```
<ion-fab right bottom #fab></ion-fab>
<help-overlay content="Click here"></help-overlay>
```

I want my help-overlay to be positionned at the same place as the ion-fab. How can I get a reference to ion-fab ?
I already tried to pass `fab` to an input of the `help-overlay` but it doesn't help much.

What's the best way to do that ion angular2 ?

The idea is to create something like this (the red button is the ion-fab and the blue circle is the help-overlay):

[image: What I want to build]

Answer (score 1):

It is more of a CSS question than Angular. Use CSS `position: absolute;` to render these two elements at the same coordinates.

Comment: No because the ion-fab can be at different positions. So I have to get it's real position using AngularJS.

Comment: Is the height of the ion-fab fixed? Then `position: relative; top: -height` should work.

Comment: The elements have the same parent. If ion-fab was the parent it would have work but that's not the case here.

Comment: What I want is something like this: http://imgur.com/a/BeAqI (the red circle is the fab and the blue around is the help-overlay. Currently those are positionned manually via position absolute.

Comment: This one is fine but you fix the position of the red circle. In my case the red circle can be on top, bottom, center, left or right. Thus I'm looking for a dynamic solution.